# Azure DevOps generate a password inside of the bash task

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops

I would like to generate a password inside of the bash task. I came up with the following:

```
- task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Bash generate password'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        password=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%^&*()\-+=' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)

        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=password]$password"
```

Unfortunately this seems to be not working, cause the task is running forever. The agent is Linux machine.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/ ?

Comment: This is exetly the page I used in order to come up this the statement for password generation, but it does nt work

Comment: try another one? there are 10 of them there?

Comment: It's possibile to improve the security of the script by setting issecret=true in the echo expression. See my post below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

`password=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%^&*()\-+=' | head -c24)`

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old thread, but this way if you set the pipeline variable "System.Debug" you can see the password printed in the pipeline Log.

The solution proposed by @[mibrl12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5333782/mibrl12) can be improved adding **issecret=true** in the echo expression, as stated in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-a-variable-as-secret):

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash generate password'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      password=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%^&*()\-+=' | head -c24)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=password;issecret=true]$password"
```

Hope it may helps.